# My listView add elements that I don't expect

Tags: android, listview, layout

In my listView I want to display only tree fields that I get from my Activity and I'm adding a layout on the top and the bottom of my listView, I'm getting the correct content of my listView but I'm getting also some elements from outsider layout.

I don't know why those outsider elements came in the listView , here is my layout code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Retour" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top_control_bar"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/note"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateNote"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/remarqueNote"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_control_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <include layout="@layout/header3" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/prenom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nomMatiere"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: This really doesn't make sense to me, maybe a screenshot could help.

Comment: sorry , but i can't post an image here cos i dont have much reputation's points , but i can try explain more :
in my list view i get the 3 fields displayed (@+id/note , @+id/dateNote , @+id/remarqueNote) but i get also in every liste item the button in the @+id/bottom_control_bar layout and the the included layout @layout/header3.

i hope it's clear enough.

Comment: You can't inline an image, but you can post a link to one regardless of your reputation level.

Comment: here is a link for a screenshot
[link](http://postimage.org/image/5mvb2fi0h/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it .
the wrong thing is that i was using the same layout for the main activity and the listView.

Answer (score 0):

OK, as far as I can see, what you've defined is a row with three text views, a row with a header,
a row with two text views, and a row with one text view.

On top of this is the ListView, and on top of that is a button. Kinda like

=========================

### | |button|              |

| listview              |
|                       |

### | ...                   |

### | |text| |text| |text|  |

### | |header|              |

### | |text| |text|         |

## | |text|                |

If this is not what you want, you're gonna have to start over.

I'd do it all with RelativeLayouts. LinearLayouts don't give you enough placement control. If you want to make a "row" of TextViews inside a RelativeLayout, encapsulate them in a RelativeLayout.

In your case, I'd put the button and the ListView as immediate children of the RelativeLayout. Create another RelativeLayout, put it inside the first one. At the top of it, put the header. Next, insert another RL within the second one, and in it put the 3 text views. Insert a second RL below this RL with the two text views, etc.

Comment: all my element are well placed , the problem is that withing the ListView i have the 3 fields that i want to display + fields from outside the listView ( the bottom button and text from the header )

Comment: @leonidas79 post a screenshot/a link to a screenshot, so we can imagine what you are talking about

Comment: it's solved , i was using the same view for the Activity and the listView , this was my problem